# Change git .ssh credential location

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

I am trying to pull the repo from my bitbucket repository. However when I do this I get the following error.

```
Could not create directory '/f/.ssh' (No such file or directory).
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/f/.ssh/known_hosts)
```

I see that git is trying to access my /f/ drive, however because it is a network drive the contents can change. I have a /c/ drive that has an .ssh folder in it but I cannot get git to recognize that drive instead of defaulting to the /f/ drive.

I am running git bash in my C drive. And I have tried reinstalling git with my /f/ drive disconnected.
How can I get git to see my `users/ssh` folder?

Comment: `ssh` usually stores its information relative to the path specified in `$HOME` environment variable. `/f/` feels like a really weird value for that variable. Did you by chance set the `HOME` variable to some value for some reason (if you did, I'd avoid that, that's a bad idea)?

Comment: No I did not set that up, but this is a work computer so I did not do all of the set up.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $HOME` in git bash? It's possible that your home directory *is* on `F:` which is a network share (which is a possible setup on Windows). In that case what it's doing is actually the correct thing to do: store your ssh config in your home directory, which happens to be a network drive.

Comment: `echo $HOME` returns `/c/Users/pc(number)`

Comment: That's weird, because that's the directory that `ssh` should try to store its config under. Can you see the entire ssh command line?

Comment: `~/.ssh $ ls id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts`
I'm able to see there's an ssh folder with all the appropriate files in the /c/ drive

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variables (`set`) in case a GIt_SSH or GIT_SSH_COMMAND would indicate a private key in `/f/...`.

Similarly, check the output, from your local repository folder, of `git config -l --show-scope --show-origin`, for anything SSH related.

Those are the two sources of settings which could explain why Git is not using `$HOME/.ssh` for its SSH operations.